# Angular: Set variable on AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angular, request

I am working on a small app and been playing around with angular. I am having this issue when clicking a button i am calling an ajax get request. On ajax success i want to set a variable to the given result. But the problem is the variables are not being set. My code is following...

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
apiEndpoint = "myapiendpoint";
searchQuery = "";
searchResult = {};

constructor() {}

onSearchSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let queryUrl = this.apiEndpoint + this.searchQuery;

    $.ajax({
      url: queryUrl,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(res) {
        this.searchResult = res;
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

When i try to set the variable searchResult it is not setting but when i console log the response directly in the success callback it gives me the whole response in console. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried logging `this` in the success callback to see what you're attaching the result to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `this`  keyword in function it will point to success function's scope and not outer scope so it wont update outer scope variable. there are two solution to this problem

**1. Use arrow function** :

```
 $.ajax({
      url: queryUrl,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "GET",
      success: (res)=>{
        this.searchResult = res;
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    });
  }
```

As arrow function dont have its own scope . `this` in arrow function always point to outer function.

**2. Copy outer `this` into one of variable and then use that variable instead of `this`** :

Copy `this` in outer function into a variable and then use that variable in ajax success function, in this case `this` will point to correct context

like below

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
apiEndpoint = "myapiendpoint";
searchQuery = "";
searchResult = {};

var that=this; // Copied this into that  variable 
constructor() {}

onSearchSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let queryUrl = this.apiEndpoint + this.searchQuery;

    $.ajax({
      url: queryUrl,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(res) {
        that.searchResult = res;// use that instead of this
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Use one of the above solution and it will solve your problem

Comment: this refers  to context object in which the current code is executing as example `foo.success() ; this => foo` not the scope 

Comment: For some reason the arrow function worked and i dont know why ... But thanks anyway ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this way by using arrow function

```
$.ajax({
  url: queryUrl,
  dataType: "json",
  method: "GET",
  success: (res) => {
    this.searchResult = res;
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("Error");
  }
});
```

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> just as recommendation stay away from jquery angular has httpModule to ahndel all http request

with httpClient

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
apiEndpoint = "myapiendpoint";
searchQuery = "";
searchResult = {};

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

onSearchSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let queryUrl = this.apiEndpoint + this.searchQuery;

    this.http.get(queryUrl).subscribe(result => this.searchResult = result );

  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[setup HttpClinetModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) This was just a quick test ... i will definitely switch over to the httpClient :)

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use jquery ajax in angular

Try to use rxjs

https://angular.io/guide/rx-library